# Different Import statements for different classes in same .py file?

Tags: python, import

In Python, I have seen that the practice of multiple classes in the same `module` or `.py file` is prevalent. But if the different classes use entirely different packages, is it possible to selectively specify import statements for the classes?

Is the following(or some variation) possible?

samefile.py:

```
import foo1
import foo2
class one
       ....
import foo2
import foo3
class two
       ....
```

Also, I saw that modules can be imported dynamically using `importlib` module, `imp` module, etc. but they require knowledge of the path to the modules, so I'm queasy about trying those.

My classes are closely related, which means it would be useful if they were in the same `.py file` (for simplicity's sake). However, they also use entirely different modules by import.

Is there a way to do this? Just wanted to know so that if not, I will have to resort to individual `.py files` for each class.

Comment: Um, what's the question? What code do you have and what code you'd like to have?

Comment: Why not just run your code and see for yourself? Hint: Yes, it's doable, but you can also just as well import everything at the top of the module (which is the suggested way of doing it).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I did, and it seemed to diregard the import statements between 2 classes. That's why I thought maybe there's another way to do it, or its not even allowed.

Comment: @Jezor Just want to know if there can be different import statements between 2 class definitions, as shown in the sample snippet.

Comment: I don't know what behaviour you have seen that makes you think they're being disregarded, but `import` statements will be executed whenever they're reached. That said, [the official style guide suggests](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) putting all imports at the top without a good reason otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly possible:

```
import collections
class Foobar(collections.OrderedDict):
  pass

import weakref
class Barfoo(weakref.WeakKeyDictionary):
  pass
```

For readability, you [should](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) have your `import`s at the top of a file. Sometimes, delayed imports may be necessary to avoid circular dependencies, however.

Comment: Thanks, I will examine my code again to see why it didn't work. Also, say I were to use Barfoo class elsewhere, would only weakref module be imported, or collections too? Sorry, I'm new to Python, so I'm lost here!

Comment: You cannot import individual classes, only modules. Even if you do `from thatmodule import Barfoo`, the entire `thatmodule` is imported. Importing runs all top-level code, including *all* class and function definitions, variable assignment, **and `import` statements**.